# Sacar un mensaje mientras mi código está cargando en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ajax, nodejs

estoy desarrollando una web y tengo ciertas consultas a la base de datos que me devuelven muchos datos, por ejemplo hay alguna con casi 10000 datos, pero no soy capaz de poner un spinner girando o un mensaje en pantalla diciendo que la web esta cargando, un ejemplo de como estoy haciendo esta consulta en mi servidor es de la siguiente manera:

```
app.get('/fincas', login, (req, res) => {
    let token = req.session.usuario.token

    let fincasDB = async() => {
        await sql.connect(config);
        let db = new sql.Request();
        db.input("token", sql.VarChar('100'), token);
        let result = await db.execute('LISTADO_CONSULTA_FINCAS');
        return result.recordset;
    }

    fincasDB().then(fincas => {
        console.log(fincas);
        res.render('fincas.hbs', { fincas: fincas });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error al sacar las fincas', err);
        return res.status(404).redirect('/404');
    });

});
```

y el ejemplo de mi frontend sería este:

```
 let nombreDeUsuario = async() => {
        let nombre = await $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/nombreUsuario",
            data: "",
            success: function(datosUsuario) {
                let usuario = datosUsuario.usuario
                return usuario;
            }
        });

        return nombre;
    }

    nombreDeUsuario().then(usuario => {
        $('#nombreUsuarioAside').text(usuario.nombre);
        $('.editarPerfil').click(function() {
            location.href = `/editarUsuario?id=${usuario.idUsuario}`;

        });

    }).catch(err => {
        alert('Ha ocurrido un error');
        location.href = "/";
    });
```

Son dos funciones diferentes que no tienen nada que ver, porque las fincas las saco por get, pero no se como poner mensajes cuando hago la consulta por ajax o cuando la hago por get, Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) que te permite ejecutar código antes de iniciar la petición, por lo cual podrías mostrar un mensaje de carga y esconderlo cuando haya acabado en el `success`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
let nombreDeUsuario = async () => {

    let nombre = await $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        data: "",
        beforeSend: function() {
            //Mostrar el loading
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        success: function(datos) {
            //Cuando hemos acabado, quitamos el loading
            $("#loading").hide();
            console.log("Done");
            return datos;
        }
    });

    return nombre;
}

nombreDeUsuario();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h2 id="loading"style="display:none">Loading...</h2>
```

> Depende de tu velocidad el cargar se mostrara más tiempo o menos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo que suelo hacer es obtener un gif de un loader, creo un div con este loader:

```
<div id="loader" style="display: none">
    <img src="img/loader.gif" alt="loader">
</div>
```

Con CSS aplicas el siguiete estilo:

```
#loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Antes de iniciar la petición ajax, ejecutas `$('#loader').fadeIn();` y al terminar, tanto en `success` como en `error` ejecutas `('#loader').fadeOut();`

Si no quieres un loader, puedes poner el mensaje, mientras dure la petición, no se va a poder interactuar con tu página

Comment: Pero si tengo 10000 datos, la web me tarda unos 5 minutos en cargar los datos, como puedo hacer que me pinte los datos de forma paginada? para que no se me queden cargando los datos durante 5 minutos e ir viendo los datos de forma correcta poco a poco

Comment: Al ser una petición asíncrona, hasta que esta no termine no vas a poder ver los resultados